# Keyboard shortcut for toggling through input sources not working for more than 2 languages

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, language

I'm using default keyboard shortcuts on Big Sur to switch between input sources:

[image]

And I have 3 languages set up (English, Japanese, Korean). But when I use ^Space it only toggles between English and Japanese. If I select Korean through the menu bar, then afterwards it only toggles between English and Korean. How do I get ^Space to cycle through all 3 input sources?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm a dummy. I'm posting a self-answered question for the other dummies out there. Because as a dummy I was confounded that I couldn't find anyone else with this "problem."

I didn't carefully read the description of the two keyboard shortcuts and assumed they both cycled through input sources, just in different directions. But no, ^Space toggles between your current and previous *selected* input sources, while ^⌥Space cycles through input sources *in the menu*.

So I disabled the first and reassigned ^Space to the second:

[image]